# Can Run Import Voila, but Error 404: Not Found - you are requesting a page that does not exist

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, voila

I keep receiving Error 404: Not Found - You are requesting a page that does not exist when I click the Voila button. I have tried moving the notebook file to my root folder so just C:Users and receive the same error. I have ensured that Voila is downloaded: `Requirement already satisfied: voila in c:\users\name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.3.8)` and have ran `import viola` successfully. Also tried on Edge and Chrome for the heck of it and still can't get around the error.

Comment: Do you mean [Voila](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila)?

Comment: How did you install Voila in the first place? Hopefully you use Anaconda/conda? The import working definitely is a positive thing; however, being able to switch modes is a larger thing than typical packages need to pull off, and I'd imaging a more complete install from Anaconda/conda than pip. Are you able to use the command line launching Voila mode approach illustrated [on the main page of the documentation](https://voila.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)?

Comment: Thanks for the advice Wayne, I used pip originally. I just switched from Jupyter Notebook to JupyterLab, following these instructions https://voila.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contribute.html to download appropriate packages and now Voila works for me!

Comment: @Wayne Now I am trying to deploy my Voila product using myBinder and it shows the same 404 error message, though Voila works in JupyterLab, just not Notebook. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you share your repository URL? If you do that, I can advise you much better and give you the URL to launch to Voila render directly. On the JupyterLab vs, Notebook... last I knew Voila mode switch via the button worked in both JupyterLab and notebook. I'll look at one of mine and report.

Comment: Notebook to Voila mode button works on MyBinder now. See demonstration from [this notebook](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/fomightez/communication_voila/master?filepath=notebooks%2Fbasics.ipynb). Voila mode switch via the button works differently from the notebook than it does from JupyterLab, & so it requires more installed behind-the-scenes to work. If your image build step isn't installing it right it won't be able to switch modes via proxy. In JupyterLab it doesn't need a proxy because it renders it in a separate pane & so it will work even if you install viola in the already running session.

Comment: @Wayne Thank you so much for the help! I uninstalled and reinstalled Voila and then also moved the file to my root directory and it worked now with Notebook/MyBinder!